# lightdm(lightdm-gtk-greeter) black screen when reboot/poweroff

Tags: linux

I have a extend monitor connected to my laptop.

ArchLinux + systemd + lightdm + lightdm-gtk-greeter.

When I execute reboot or poweroff command, Both of the 2 monitor will show an black screen(I can see an cursor on top-left corner of my laptop's screen).Nether reboot nor poweroff operation will be taken place.

If I switch to an console tty with ctrl+alt+f1 hotkey, then execute reboot/poweroff command, then reboot/poweroff operation will be correctly processed.

I'v found some error message in /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log :

```
[root@XSign hacksign]# cat /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log

X.Org X Server 1.18.3
Release Date: 2016-04-04
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.2.5-1-ARCH x86_64 
Current Operating System: Linux XSign 4.5.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 11 22:21:28 CEST 2016 x86_64
Kernel command line: initrd=\initramfs-linux.img root=/dev/sda3 rw
Build Date: 05 April 2016  05:24:02PM

Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon May 30 13:08:38 2016
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xf86: remove device 0 /sys/devices
```

Any body knows how to solved this problem ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as required for Stackoverflow questions. Your question may be appropriate for other sites such as [Unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but do check their help first before posting.

Comment: sorry for that, I'm repost this one to superuser.Please close If anyone can do this ~